# Implement Load More Pagination with GSON Data from AsyncTask

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello everyone I've created a RecyclerView and get the data with AsyncTask. In the first step I want is to display 10 first data and load more 10 data until it reach the last data. 
After that I want to implement a progressbar as a footer to load data.

here is my code for my MutationRecyclerViewAdapter

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_mutation, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.mItem = mValues[position]
    holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.text = getTransactionTypeString(mValues[position].transactionType)
    holder.itemView.text_transaction_number.text = mValues[position].transactionID
    holder.itemView.text_transaction_date.text = AppUtil.getDefaultDateFormat(mValues[position].transactionDate)
    holder.itemView.text_balance.text = mValues[position].balance
    holder.itemView.text_amount.text = mValues[position].amount
    holder.itemView.text_merchant_name.text = mValues[position].merchant

    if(mValues[position].transactionType != null) {
        when (mValues[position].transactionType) {
            "PR", "ST" -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_purchase)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.orange))
                holder.itemView.text_product_name.text = holder.mItem!!.merchant
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.orange))
                //holder.itemView.text_product_name.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_min_orange)
            }
            "RD" -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_withdraw_rotated)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.orange))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_plus)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.orange))
            }
            "CI" -> {
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.green_grass_dark))
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.bg_circle_green)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cash_in)
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_plus_green)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green_grass_dark))
            }
            "CO", "FCO", "XX" -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_withdraw_rotated)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.orange))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_min_orange)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.orange))
            }
            "AD" -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_adjustment)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle_gray)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_plus)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))

            }
            "RBY"->{
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_adjustment)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle_gray)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_plus)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
            }
            "TO" -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle_blue)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_transfer)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.blue_foreground))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_minus_blue)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.blue_foreground))

            }
            "TI", "BY" -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle_green)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_transfer_in)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext!!, R.color.green_grass_dark))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_plus_green)
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green_grass_dark))
            }
            else -> {
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_adjustment)
                holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle_gray)
                holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
                holder.itemView.image_balance.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
            }
        }
    } else {
        holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_adjustment)
        holder.itemView.image_transaction_icon.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.bg_circle_gray)
        holder.itemView.text_transaction_type.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
        holder.itemView.image_balance.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        holder.itemView.text_amount.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.gray_dark))
    }

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener {
        mListener?.onMutationFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem!!)
    }
    holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener {
        mListener?.onLongMutationFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem!!)
        false
    }
}

private fun getTransactionTypeString(type: String): String {
    return when(type) {
        "PR" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.purchase)
        "CI" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.cash_in)
        "CO" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.cash_out)
        "RD" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.redeem)
        "TI" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.transfer_in)
        "TO" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.transfer_out)
        "FCO" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.cash_out)
        "XX" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.cash_out)
        "BY" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.purchase)
        "ST" ->  mContext!!.getString(R.string.settlement)
        "AD" -> mContext!!.getString(R.string.adjustment)
        "RBY" ->mContext!!.getString(R.string.rby)
        else -> return type
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mValues.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(val mView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView) {
    var mItem: MutationItem? = null
}
```

and this my MutationFragment

```
private var maxItemSize = -1
private var mListener: OnMutationFragmentInteractionListener? = null
lateinit var adapter : MutationRecyclerViewAdapter
lateinit var refreshButton : ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (arguments != null) {
        maxItemSize = arguments?.getInt(MAX_ITEMS_SIZE, -1)!!
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mutation, container, false)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "MutationFragment"
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    MutationContent.ITEMS.clear()

    GetTransactionTask(context!!, this).execute()
    mutation_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    adapter = MutationRecyclerViewAdapter(MutationContent.getSavedTransactions(context, maxItemSize), mListener, context)

    refreshLayout.apply {
        scrollUpChild = mutation_list
        setOnRefreshListener {
            isRefreshing = false
            GetTransactionTask(context!!, this@MutationFragment).execute()
        }
    }

}

fun toggleView(isEmpty : Boolean){
    if(isEmpty){
        progress_bar?.visibility = View.GONE
        mutation_list?.visibility = View.GONE
        //refreshButton.visibility = View.GONE
        text_no_mutation?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else{
        progress_bar?.visibility = View.GONE
        mutation_list?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        //refreshButton?.visibility = View.GONE
        text_no_mutation?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()
}

override fun onGetTransactionSuccess(response: ResponseRequestMutasiSaldo) {
    MutationContent.import(context, response, maxItemSize)
    adapter = MutationRecyclerViewAdapter(MutationContent.getSavedTransactions(context, maxItemSize),
            mListener, context)
    mutation_list?.adapter = adapter
    if(adapter.mValues.isEmpty()) {
        text_no_mutation?.setText(getString(R.string.no_mutation))
    } else {
        text_no_mutation?.setText(getString(R.string.load_mutation))
    }
    toggleView(adapter.mValues.isEmpty())
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnMutationFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context!!.toString() + " must implement OnSettingFragmentInteractionListener")
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    mListener = null
}

override fun onTransactionFailed(response: ResponseRequestMutasiSaldo) {
    adapter = MutationRecyclerViewAdapter(
            MutationContent.getSavedTransactions(context, maxItemSize),
            mListener, context)
    mutation_list?.adapter = adapter
    toggleView(adapter.mValues.isEmpty())
    /*if(activity != null)
        Toasty.error(activity!!,response.errorMessage).show()*/
}

interface OnMutationFragmentInteractionListener {
    fun onMutationFragmentInteraction(item: MutationItem)
    fun onLongMutationFragmentInteraction(item: MutationItem)
}

companion object {
    val MAX_ITEMS_SIZE = "MAX_ITEM_SIZE"
}
```

and this my Asynctask Class

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): ResponseRequestMutasiSaldo? {
    return ResourceService(context).requestMutasiSaldo()
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: ResponseRequestMutasiSaldo?) {
    if(result != null && (result.error.equals(AppUtil.RESPONSE_ERROR_CODE_EXPIRY) || result.success.equals(AppUtil.RESPONSE_SUCCESS_CODE_EXPIRY))){
        EventBus.getDefault().post(SessionExpiry(result.message?:""))
        return
    }
    if(result != null && result.success.equals("1")) {
        listener.onGetTransactionSuccess(result)
    }
    if(result != null && result.error.equals("1")){
        listener.onTransactionFailed(result)
        return
    }
}
```

I have successfully got all the data from web service and now I've tried, using EndlessRecyclerViewListener like in this [documentation](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView#implementing-with-recyclerview) and using several references to achive my task. But the function AddOnScroll didn't work properly and I didn't understand well how this work. How do I do if I want to use EndlessRecyclerViewListener? Or is there any other way to achive this without using EndlessRecyclerViewListener class?

Answer (score 0):

Use addOnScrollListener to do this.

```
val pageLimit: Int = 10//row returned each time on scroll
var noMoreItems: Boolean = false
```

use `addOnScrollListener` in your recyclerview like this.

```
dataRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    if (!utility.isConnected(mContext)) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return
                    }

                    if (noMoreItems)
                        return
                    val lastPage: String
                    val nextPage: Int
                    if (dataArrayList.size > 0) {
                        lastPage = ((dataArrayList.size - 1) / pageLimit).toInt().toString()
                        nextPage = Integer.parseInt(lastPage) + 1
                    } else {
                        nextPage = 1;
                    }
                    loadRecords(nextPage.toString())
                }
            }
        })
```

here in `loadRecords()` you should call your `asynctask` with page number.
set `noMOreItems=true` when number of rows returned is less than `pageLimit`.

Comment: first im thankful for your answer, but i didnt understand why you parse the array data into String? you see my arrayList is an object (MutationItem), and why i should call my `asyntask` again inside addOnScroll while i already called my asynctask in `onViewCreate` didnt it will load the data again from begining?

Comment: I parsed last page to string only cause my loadRecords() accept string only. Its your wish ,you can keep page number  integer and I load data from network call in async task each time 10 rows. So I call each time the asynctask to load next 10 when user scroll to bottom of list.

Comment: i get it for parse, but how your `asynctask` load next 10 data after first 10 data showed. you see my `asynctask` class is done to **get all the data** ie. the data in service is 25 so when i call my `asynctask` it show all 25 data, and if i recall my `asyntask` again after 10 data it will show and start the begining data again and didnt continue the next 10 data. with your approach what i get is i need to make another `asynctask` class or rebuild my `asynctask` and my web service to just only show 10 each isn't it?

Comment: look I am calculating nextPage number from number of data loaded dataArrayList.size . i.e. if 20 rows added already then current page is 2 and next page is 3. So I only load data (10*2)+1 to (10*3) that means 21 to 30th rows only and append those to my main list

Comment: i understand about that. Im sorry it seems you didnt get it about what i mean. im asking about the `asynctask`. look my `asynctask` purposely done for **get all data**. If i call my `asynctask` again after nextPage it will execute to get all of my data.This is why i ask is how you `asynctask` perform like you said. like i said before i already call my `asynctask` class inside of `onViewCreate` if i call my asynctask again it will perform the same result

Comment: if you have all of the data in first call then why do you  want to make pagination.. load more!

Comment: im sorry it seems is my mistake to said pagination in the title. And yess i want to perform load more in my list with 10 first data and load more again. thats why i asking if there is a other way to archive this, if i already had the all data i get from my asyntask?

Comment: then create another tempList for recyclerview. instead of calling asynctask in loadRecords() just return next n to n+10th indexed data from allDataList and add to templist .call notifyDatasetChanged() in your adapter